how can I convert hourly data to daily Max, Aver... and Min
this is an hourly TMP data so want to convert it to daily Max, Avr and Min I did once in excell but the result is not resonable.
this data need preprocessing so I just applied some function like finding the average i just used the function average to get the average data for a single day but the result is not good,so I need some other methods which is accurate and best.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
